# Pydub of Python doesn't work-Probably ffmpeg installed wrongfully

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pydub

I have recently downloaded and installed `Pydub` but it doesn't work.

I installed it with pip and then downloaded and installed `ffmpeg`. Whenever I try to import the library or write a simple code, I get this error message:

> RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg,
>   but may not work .

Could someone explain to me what I've been doing wrong??

What is the problem with ffmpeg?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454002/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried to install again ffmpeg. Now, I don't get the same error when I try to import the library.However, when I tried to run the test.py, I get a lo of errors. 
Is there some kind of documentation for the library or some code examples??

Comment: Try debugging your code and post a question here if you get a specific error you are unsure of.  I'm not entirely sure what you are doing, so either check out the ffmpeg library documentation

Comment: Sorry for asking again but I'm new with Python.
Could you please explain to me, how exactly should I install pydub and ffmpeg?? Maybe I have made some mistakes, that I'm not aware of ,from the beginning.
Please help me if you can, because I have a very important project to make for the semester at university

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#installation) on the github page.  It looks like there are good instructions to help get this setup.

Comment: @Amstell you're right that it's a duplicate. We added this RuntimeWarning to help users debug their configuration (rather than allowing the more confusing `FileNotFoundError` to bubble up later on)